# Upload .app file to Hockey app using Jenkins

Tags: xcode, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, hockeyapp

I have created a job in jenkins for Mac application. I am able to build the app successfully. The problem is I am unable to upload the ***.app*** file to Hockey app.
It was described in Hockey Jenkins plugin we need ***.app.zip*** (MacOS).
I am unable to create .app.zip file. 
How to create such kind of file or is there any other way we can upload the .app to Hockeyapp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, you shouldn't have a `.app` file — it should be a directory.

Xcode should be able to create both the `Something.app` directory and a `Something.app.zip` file.

If you can't find a `.app.zip` file in the build output, you should be able to create one yourself by zipping the `.app` directory.

e.g. From Jenkins, you could add an "Execute shell" build step that just does:

```
cd <app-output-dir>; zip -r9 Something.app.zip Something.app
```

Then from the HockeyApp plugin, you can choose `**/*.app.zip` as the file to upload.

Comment: Can we upload ipa to hockey app using script? If yes, then can you please guide me about the related script.